# Is there a way to install a dll into the GAC in a VSI file

Tags: visual-studio

I created a Visual Studio Project Template that includes a Wizard Extension.  Is there a way to have that assembly installed into the GAC by the VSI installer file?  I looked around MSDN, but I don't see anything about automating that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is with a custom wizard step: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx.